# How would I define width for a slideshow?

Tags: html, css

How I would make an image in a slideshow fit everyones monitor?

For example if I have slideshow images that are 1300 x 300 what if someones monitor is a lot bigger?

Comment: provide your code or link to your slideshow

Comment: You can do it like `$('img').css('width', $(window).width());` let me know if you are looking for this kind of solution?

Comment: It wont let me put code in as its too much :(

Answer (score 0):

You simple set your slideshow container CSS class to width:100%;
If you post a link to your slideshow I can show you.